# Views UI affected due to multiple modules

Tags: 7, views, javascript

jquery.once is perfectly working, I placed console.log inside it, but I still get this error especially when I load the Views UI without even before I press any button

When I press any button, a progress animation appears and again this error appears

```
views-admin.js?op2hqg:164 Uncaught TypeError: $form.once is not a function
    at Object.Drupal.behaviors.addItemForm.attach (views-admin.js?op2hqg:164)
```

When I investigates I found that the following jquery select returns 0 objects

```
var $form = $(context).find('form[id^="views-ui-add-item-form"]').first();
```

How to solve this, should I disable any modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen when you use jQuery Update, I faced the same and solved using CDN providers

Use jQuery CDN Provider in your jQuery Update Settings should solve this issue

Load your settings as yoursite.com/admin/config/development/jquery_update, You will see the option **jQuery and jQuery UI CDN** with None in the dropdown list.

Choose **jQuery** and **Save Configuration**